# Replace a data frame column based on regex

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract part of a column in a data frame using regular expressions. Problems I am running into include the facts that `grep` returns the whole value, not just the matched part, and that `str_extract` doesn't seem to work in a vectorized way.

Here is what I'm trying. I would like `df$match` to show `alpha.alpha.` where the pattern exists and `NA` otherwise. How can I show only the matched part?

Also, how I can I replace `[a-zA-Z]` in R regex? Can I use a character class or a POSIX code like `[:alpha:]`?

```
v1 <- c(1:4)
v2 <- c("_a.b._", NA, "_C.D._", "_ef_")
df <- data.frame(v1, v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$match <- grepl("[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.", df$v2)
df$match

#TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

v2grep <- grep("[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.", df$v2, value = TRUE)

df$match[df$match == TRUE] <- v2grep
df$match[df$match == FALSE] <- NA

df

#v1  v2      match
#1   _a.b._  _a.b._
#2   <NA>    <NA>
#3   _C.D._  _C.D._
#4   _ef_    <NA>
```

What I want:

```
#v1  v2      match
#1   _a.b._  a.b.
#2   <NA>    <NA>
#3   _C.D._  C.D.
#4   _ef_    <NA>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**4 Approaches...**

Here's 2 approaches in base as well as with `rm_default(extract=TRUE)` in the **qdapRegex** package I maintain and the **stringi** package.

```
unlist(sapply(regmatches(df[["v2"]], gregexpr("[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.", df[["v2"]])), function(x){
        ifelse(identical(character(0), x), NA, x)
    })
)

## [1] "a.b." NA     "C.D." NA 

pat <- "(.*?)([a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.)(.*?)$"
df[["v2"]][!grepl(pat, df[["v2"]])] <- NA
df[["v2"]] <- gsub(pat, "\\2", df[["v2"]])

## [1] "a.b." NA     "C.D." NA

library(qdapRegex)
unlist(rm_default(df[["v2"]], pattern = "[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.", extract = TRUE))

## [1] "a.b." NA     "C.D." NA 

library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(df[["v2"]], "[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.")

## [1] "a.b." NA     "C.D." NA
```

Comment: I like the `strringi` solution. This is really a rich package, there's a lot one can do with it when taking time to study it!

Comment: The `stringi` seems to do just what I need easily. Will it also allow me to separate out parts of a pattern, like you do with `gsub(pat, "\\2", df[["v2"]])` in your second solution?

Comment: Yes but you need a different pattern and possibly function depending on what you are after.

Comment: Please see my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543785/how-can-i-split-a-column-in-a-dataframe-by-regex)

Answer (score 4):

Base R solution using `regmatches`, and `regexpr` which returns `-1` if no regex match is found:

```
r <- regexpr("[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.", df$v2)
df$match <- NA
df$match[which(r != -1)] <- regmatches(df$v2, r)

#  v1     v2 match
#1  1 _a.b._  a.b.
#2  2   <NA>  <NA>
#3  3 _C.D._  C.D.
#4  4   _ef_  <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution using both `grepl` and `sub`:

```
# First, remove unwanted characters around pattern when detected
df$match <- sub(pattern = ".*([a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.).*", 
                replacement = "\\1", x = df$v2)
# Second, check if pattern is present; otherwise set to NA
df$match <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = "[a-zA-Z]\\.[a-zA-Z]\\.", x = df$match),
                   yes = df$match, no = NA)
```

**Results**

```
df

#   v1     v2 match
# 1  1 _a.b._  a.b.
# 2  2   <NA>  <NA>
# 3  3 _C.D._  C.D.
# 4  4   _ef_  <NA>
```

**Data**

```
v1 <- c(1:4)
v2 <- c("_a.b._", NA, "_C.D._", "_ef_")
df <- data.frame(v1, v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `"\\1`" does? Does it refer to the first grouped `()` section in the pattern? It seems straightforward here, but when I experiment in something more complicated it doesn't seem to work exactly that way. Is there a good resource for that kind of notation?

Comment: Yes, the `\\1` refers to the first (and only, this time) grouped pattern (inside parentheses). When you have several groups of parentheses, and some nested in others, it becomes a little bit more tricky, but still pretty straightforward. For sources, `?regex` is a good start (and has other links at the end).