# How can I split a column in a dataframe by regex?

Tags: regex, r

Example:

```
ID <- c(1:5)
v1 <- c("abc1", "d2", "eF34", "GHi567", "NoNumber")
df <- data.frame(ID, v1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to do something like the following, but in simpler code and possibly one function. `str_match_all` in `stringr` would be good, but it requires an atomic vector. I suppose I could write in a row loop, but I'd like something already vectorized. Will something in `stringi` be useful here?

```
pattern1 <- "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)"
df$v2 <- sub(pattern = pattern1, replacement = "\\1", x = df$v1)
df$v3 <- sub(pattern = pattern1, replacement = "\\2", x = df$v1)
```

Also, I'd like to be able to handle the matching issue in Row 5, making `df$v3[5] <- NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be splitting the string (`strsplit`) by specifying the `lookaround` as pattern, and convert the 'list' output to 'matrix using `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`.  This will pad `NA` to list elements that have length less than the maximum list element length.

```
library(stringi)
df[paste0('v', 2:3)] <- stri_list2matrix(strsplit(df$v1,
                  '(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])', perl=TRUE), byrow=TRUE)

 df
 #  ID       v1       v2   v3
 #1  1     abc1      abc    1
 #2  2       d2        d    2
 #3  3     eF34       eF   34
 #4  4   GHi567      GHi  567
 #5  5 NoNumber NoNumber <NA>
```

Or use `extract` from `tidyr`.  We can `paste` the strings that don't have a numeric element at the end with `NA` and use `extract`.  This also have the option to convert the 'class' by specifying `convert=TRUE`.

```
library(tidyr)
df$v1 <- with(df, ifelse(grepl('\\d+$', v1),v1, paste0(v1,NA)) )
extract(df, v1, into=c('v2', 'v3'), '([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+|NA)', 
             remove=FALSE, convert=TRUE)
#   ID         v1       v2  v3
#1  1       abc1      abc   1
#2  2         d2        d   2
#3  3       eF34       eF  34
#4  4     GHi567      GHi 567
#5  5 NoNumberNA NoNumber  NA
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
df[paste0('v', 2:3)] <- read.table(text=gsub('([A-Za-z]*)([0-9]*)',
    '\\1 \\2', df$v1), header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: I haven't used perl regex. In the first solution, is perl necessary? I didn't get the `strsplit` to work without it. What do `?<=` and `?=` do?

Comment: @KevinM Yes it is needed as we are using the `lookahead` and `lookbehind` pattern to specify the boundary between the `character` and `numeric` elements.  You can check this link to learn more about the lookaround http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Seeing `<NA>` makes me think the first version is delivering the digits as factor which I think was not what was requested.

Comment: @BondedDust Actually it is `character` column.  `str(df$v3)
 #chr [1:5] "1" "2" "34" "567" NA`.  It can be converted back to `numeric`, but I left it as such because the OP's code was not converting it to numeric.  In the other two options, it is numeric.

Comment: Could have gotten character "" just by changing the `"*"` to `"?"` following the second capture phrase.

Comment: @BondedDust I guess you are talking about the `read.table`.  But, it changed the 2 columns to 4 columns for me. `str(read.table(text=gsub('([A-Za-z]*)([0-9]?)', '\\1 \\2', df$v1), header=FALSE, fill=TRUE))
'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:`

Comment: I was hoping for a function that would split a column into other columns in much the same way that `str_match` from `stringr` splits regex matches into multiple columns of a matrix based on `()` groups.

Comment: I'm not well versed in "lookarounds". I'll check out that page. As far as numeric or character for v3, that doesn't matter for this example.

Comment: @KevinM There are multiple options as I described in my post and more..  Choosing the right option is a bit subjective.  I guess the `stringi` option would be fast along with `strsplit`.

Comment: What about the `stri_extract` functions in `stringi`? They don't handle this?

Comment: @KevinM  Yes you can get a list using `stri_extract_all_regex(df$v1, '[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+')` and from there use `stri_list2matrix`

Answer (score 2):

Slight mod to pattern and using `as.numeric` for coercion to proper class:

```
pattern1 <- "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]*)"
df$v2 <- sub(pattern = pattern1, replacement = "\\1", x = df$v1)
 df$v3 <- as.numeric(sub(pattern = pattern1, replacement = "\\2", x = df$v1))
 df

  ID       v1       v2  v3
1  1     abc1      abc   1
2  2       d2        d   2
3  3     eF34      eF4  34
4  4   GHi567    GHi67 567
5  5 NoNumber NoNumber  NA
```

Comment: I think the pattern should have `*` instead of `?`. The `?` screws up `df$v2`. One problem with using `sub` is that the whole string will appear if there isn't a match. Would you suggest combining it with something like `grepl`? See this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529021/replace-a-data-frame-column-based-on-regex/) of mine.

Comment: You probably right about the swap of '?' and '*'. It may have been accidental that it worked with this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using [development version of data.table, v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.5
setDT(df)[, c("c1", "c2") := tstrsplit(v1, "(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE)]
#    ID       v1       c1  c2
# 1:  1     abc1      abc   1
# 2:  2       d2        d   2
# 3:  3     eF34       eF  34
# 4:  4   GHi567      GHi 567
# 5:  5 NoNumber NoNumber  NA
```

regex borrowed from @akrun. Use `type.convert=TRUE` if you want `c2` to be converted to numeric automatically during `tstrsplit()`.

Comment: Looks pretty powerful and is the type of thing I was hoping to see. I'm probably not advanced enough to mess with development versions, but I'll watch for the release.

Comment: Thanks. In data.table, odd numbered versions are considered "devel" and even numbered are on CRAN.. They are development not in the sense of "unstable". So you can safely install them. But I'll leave you to it..

Comment: @Arun Looks good, I just noticed the `fill` argument in `tstrsplit`