# R several conditions for transform data.frame

Tags: r, conditional-statements, transformation

I wish to eliminate the string "DK","DK/NA" and so on. I succeed to do this with this line. But,  I think, there should be a better way to do this?
Thx

```
quali_100[quali_100 == "DK" | quali_100=="DK/NA" |quali_100=="Refusal" | quali_100=="DK/No op"] <- "NA"
```

Comment: `quali_100[quali_100 %in% c("DK", "DK/NA", "Refusal", "DK/No op")] <- "NA"`

Comment: Can you provide some example data? You'll use some type of regex or grepl, rather than specifying each condition to remove. See [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529021/replace-a-data-frame-column-based-on-regex).